# Why does jpa not create table?

Tags: java, jpa, entity

I have some classes in my java spring boot project. I use jpa and xampp for localhost. All the Entity classes work and create tables for every @Entity class. But this class does not work. Why?

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class Match {
    @Id
    private String matchId;
    @Enumerated
    private MatchType matchType;
}
```

Comment: What the difference between this class and a class that works?

Comment: `Match` is a reserved keyword in MySQL, so possibly it doesn't allow a table by that name to be created.

Comment: I guess Matnh is reserved and also check ddl-auto: true in your properties

Comment: Create another entity named Where, see if it's working.

Comment: i even dont know what's the reason. every classes with @Entity tag creates table in databse but this doesnot

Comment: spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/game_db
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

Comment: what does your DEBUGGING tell you? like looking in the LOG of your chosen JPA provider? You have looked?

Comment: Are the other classes listed in the persistence.xml? How are they added to the persistence unit?  Check that this one is also, either within the persistence.xml or within the same directory structure during runtime.

Comment: https://github.com/KamrulHasan-Seu/Research-Methodology/tree/master/Game_Backend/src/main              Here my repository.I changed that class name but it does not crete any table and make some error when i run this program. Anyone help pls.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"Match"\")
public class Match {
    @Id
    private String matchId;
    @Enumerated
    private MatchType matchType;
}
```

More general, if you set

> hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true

every identifier gets quoted.